# google maps direction api: python vs javascript

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am facing this weird problem. I've been using the google maps APIs using javascript the whole while and now had to use google maps API using python for some reason.
The issue I'm facing is that I get different data in JS and python for the same source and destination. To be specific, I am not getting the `path` variable in the response JSON when using python google maps.

```py
import googlemaps 
from datetime import datetime 

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API_KEY') 
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA') 

reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452)) 

now = datetime.now() 
directions_result = gmaps.directions("Silk Board, Bengaluru", "Indira Nagar, Bengaluru", mode="transit", departure_time=now) 
print(directions_result)
```

The data I get using python: [image]

The data I get using JS:[image]

As you can see, the `path` is missing.

I am using [python-googlemaps'](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) direction API.
I also tried using request module and using the google direction API using https links but still the received data is the same.
Is python supposed to behave this way or am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you call the API using JS?

Comment: I used googleapis.com as my source. Similar to this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple#maps_directions_simple-javascript).

Comment: Can you share your Python call? Remember to remove your API keys

Comment: `import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API_KEY') 
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452))
now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions("Silk Board, Bengaluru",
                                "Indira Nagar, Bengaluru",
                                 mode="transit",
                                 departure_time=now)
print(directions_result)` I tried changing the mode to 'DRIVING' as that was what I used in JS

Comment: have you tried `mode="driving"`?

Comment: Yep. I tried out all the available modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the google tech support and looks like the data is intended to be this way. If you want to get the co-ordinates of the entire route like I wanted, you can use the "polyline" field that comes in as a response.

The polyline will be in an encoded format. You can use [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) link to decode the data into the required co-ordinates or you can also use the polyline library(available in python) for the same.